# Read List from JSON file

Tags: json, list, dictionary, arraylist, jackson

I've been trying without success to implement a method to read a nested ArraList from a JSON file.

My JSON file has the following structure:

```
 {
  "INT": {
    "Company": "mock company",
    "id": "0123456789X",
    "IntegerForm" : [1, 5, 7, 10],
    "StringForm": ["string 1", "string 2", "string 3"],
    "NestedMap" : {
        "key1" : "value1",
        "key2" : "value2"
    }
  },
  "TEST": {
    "Company": "mock company",
    "id": "0123456789X",
    "IntegerForm" : [1, 5, 7, 10],
    "StringForm": ["string 1", "string 2", "string 3"],
    "NestedMap" : {
        "key1" : "value1",
        "key2" : "value2"
    }  },
  "PRE": {
    "Company": "mock company",
    "id": "0123456789X",
    "IntegerForm" : [1, 5, 7, 10],
    "StringForm": ["string 1", "string 2", "string 3"],
    "NestedMap" : {
        "key1" : "value1",
        "key2" : "value2"
    }    
  }
}
```

I have several levels of nested Maps which I can read with the following class:

```
public class JSONMapper {
    private HashMap<?, ?> jsonMap;

    public JSONMapper(String jsonPath) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        jsonMap = objectMapper.readValue(new File(jsonPath), HashMap.class);
    }

    public HashMap<?, ?> getJsonMap(String key) {
        return (HashMap<?,?>)jsonMap.get(key);
    }
}
```

To read nested map I just need to cast them as it follows:

```
HashMap<?, ?> dataMap;
JSONMapper mapper;
mapper = new JSONMapper("src/test/resources/datatest/example.json");
dataMap = mapper.getJsonMap("TEST");
HashMap <String, HashMap<String, String>> = (HashMap <String, HashMap<String, String>>) dataMap.get("NestedMap")
```

How can I implement a similar method to read the values of IntegerForm and StringForm as a List and List respectively?
I'd like to do something like

```
new ArrayList ((List<Integer>) mapper.getJSONArray("IntegerForm"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trying multiple posted solutions I realized I was accesing a map key that (from a property file) that was not present in the json file... That's why none of the solutions I was trying didn't work.

This is my final class that can read a generic map from a JSON file if anyone is interested:

```
public class JSONMapper {
    private HashMap<String, Object> jsonMap;

    public JSONMapper(String jsonPath) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        jsonMap = objectMapper.readValue(new File(jsonPath),
            new TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>>(){});
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public HashMap<String, Object> getJsonMap(String key) {
        return (HashMap<String, Object>)jsonMap.get(key);
    }
}
```